# java- how to deploy a jar file which is on a remote machine-with some user defined arguments

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jar, virtual-machine

I am pretty new to maven/ant hence please excuse me if my question sounds silly to you...

In an application I am working on, I have to initialise a virtual machine (eg Amazon EC2 instance), then upload a JAR file to that machine and finally, run it-- each time I want to run it, the run-time arguments may be different.

What is the best way of doing this? What frameworks/libraries (like maven or ant) will I require to be installed on that virtual machine, in addition to JRE, for this to work?

Comment: This is not a job for Maven. For such purposes better use a script, a CI solution or things like Chef or Puppet.

Answer (score 1):

If you stick to `Maven`, you can <s>attack</s> attach the jar uploading process to the `install phase` as follows:

pom.xml :

```
...
<plugins>
...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <tasks>
        <scp todir="${targetNode}:~/" trust="true" failonerror="true"
          file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
      </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>upload</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
...
</plugins>
...
```

Then issue:

```
mvn clean install "-DtargetNode=user:pass@machine"
```

Optionally write a script that runs the uploaded jar on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

You likely won't need Ant/Maven deployed remotely.

Can you instead `ssh`/`scp` onto that machine ? Ant has [sshexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) and [scp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) tasks to allow you to copy and run stuff remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to create shell script that does all you need. If the machine is unix like,
you can achieve all this with ssh, scp (uses ssh).

With ssh you can execute remote shell commands.

Example (all_in_one.sh):

```
args=$1
arg2=$2
etc.
ssh admin@amazon_instance << end
/home/admin/bin/startAmazonVM.sh $arg1
end

scp mylocal.jar admin@amazon_instance:/home/admin/server/libraries/

ssh admin@amazon_instance << end
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar /home/admin/server/libraries/mylocal.jar $arg2
end
```

Then you can run e.g. all_in_one.sh  (add >> output.txt to create execution output file, which you may then parse to verify the process)

If you are working on Windows, install Cygwin or MinGW, or use ant and spend some more, more time configuring tasks in it to do the things other tools do best.